# Blender: Change selected GP stroke's material

Tags: blender

i would like to know how can i change a Grease Pencil stroke's material in GP Edit mode directly without using the operator (bpy.opsgpencil.stroke_change_color)

I am stuck trying to guess what the syntax is and i cant find anything online

I tried this:
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.data.layers[-1].frames[-1].strokes[-1].material = "solid stroke"

but it says object has no attribute 'material'

I cant find anything on the blender manual as well

Thank you in advance for answering!
I really appreciate it, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The material of a grease pencil stroke is set by an index, `material_index`. You can find that index in the `material_slots` of the GP object like so:

```python
context = bpy.context

# Get material slot index in active object
new_material_index = context.active_object.material_slots['Solid Stroke'].slot_index

# Get active layer of active object
active_layer = context.active_object.data.layers.active

# Set material for last stroke
active_layer.active_frame.strokes[-1].material_index = new_material_index
```